# There's no server side check for Close Vote reviewing your own question

Tags: bug, review, vote-to-close

As many of you know, you'll never get one of your own posts in the Close Votes review queue. This is by design - of course you would vote to leave your own question open. However, if you have [10k reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), it's rather trivial to find the review item while it's still active via the [review history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/history), if some other users have already reviewed it. Since there's no *server* side check if you're reviewing your own post, it's possible to influence or even [*complete* the review on your own post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/69394):

[image]

(This question was closed (and later reopened) anyway, because Meta is a relatively small site for the number of users who vote to close. On larger sites like Stack Overflow the question could live on as if nothing happened.)

Comment: As 10+K user you are ought to know better I think. Making this a (rare) edge case. I think it would be more effective to discipline the one or two users who game the system then to change the system.